# How to bind to document events with Blazor

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I am writing a simple snake game with Blazor, but I can't figure out how to bind to document events. I know that it is possible to bind events on different elements such as **div** or **input**. Example: `<input onkeypress="@KeyPressInDiv"/>`, where the handler is `public void KeyPressInDiv(UIKeyboardEventArgs ev) {...}`.

I suppose that there should be some equivalent to the JavaScript method `document.onkeydown = function (evt) {}`. I have found two approaches for working around this problem:

1. Use JavaScript for binding and invoke Blazor code (taken from https://github.com/aesalazar/AsteroidsWasm):

```
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('Test.ClientSide', 'JsKeyDown', evt.keyCode);

    //Prevent all but F5 and F12
    if (evt.keyCode !== 116 && evt.keyCode !== 123)
        evt.preventDefault();
};

document.onkeyup = function (evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('Test.ClientSide', 'JsKeyUp', evt.keyCode);

    //Prevent all but F5 and F12
    if (evt.keyCode !== 116 && evt.keyCode !== 123)
        evt.preventDefault();
};
```

... and in C# implement a static class with methods marked by `[JSInvokable]` and events. This works, but leads to an extreme delay on every key press.

2. It is possible to add an input tag and bind to its events. This works much faster than the previous approach, but it seems like a hack rather then a solution. Also, we are not able to listen for some actions, such as Up/Down Arrow.

Is there a direct way to bind to document events from Blazor?

**Update 1:** I created a simple project to better explain what I want to achieve: https://github.com/XelMed/BlazorSnake
There are 3 implementations of Snake:

1. Pure JS - this has the expected behavior
2. Using JS with Blazor - invoke a Blazor function from JS code with a JsInterop
3. Using input tag - bind to events on an input tag to control the snake

Comment: Here an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328157/preventdefault-on-blazor-input

Comment: How much of a delay are you seeing?  When I do logging of keypress in JS and in the C# method that receives it, I do not see more then 1-2 millisecond difference.  And that is with the logging statements - probably less without them.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps add a event listener to the document using JsInterop and assign a anonymus function to the event which calls your C# method with the even parameters.

For example your JsInterop.js:

```
document.addEventListener('onkeypress', function (e) {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('Snake', 'OnKeyPress', serializeEvent(e))
});
```

with serializeEvent being as follos to avoid some quirkiness:

```
var serializeEvent = function (e) {
    if (e) {
        var o = {
            altKey: e.altKey,
            button: e.button,
            buttons: e.buttons,
            clientX: e.clientX,
            clientY: e.clientY,
            ctrlKey: e.ctrlKey,
            metaKey: e.metaKey,
            movementX: e.movementX,
            movementY: e.movementY,
            offsetX: e.offsetX,
            offsetY: e.offsetY,
            pageX: e.pageX,
            pageY: e.pageY,
            screenX: e.screenX,
            screenY: e.screenY,
            shiftKey: e.shiftKey
        };
        return o;
    }
};
```

in your C# code you would have:

```
[JSInvokable]
public static async Task OnMouseDown(UIMouseEventArgs e){
    // Do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: Useful answer. I didn't realize before that it's impossible to pass a raw event to Blazor without serialization.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement as you, and I managed to wire up document events (e.g. keydown) to my Razor methods using invokeMethodAsync, but then I found that I missed out on the automatic DOM diffing and updating that Blazor provides if the Razor method changes some state which is bound to an HTML element (e.g. controls the visibility of a div element).

It seems (from my limited understanding of Blazor) that normally Blazor returns whatever state data is necessary to update the DOM, in the return data of a WebAssembly method.
But if you use invokeMethod or invokeMethodAsync from JavaScript, you have to manage returning and consuming this data yourself, but that might be problematic because your updates might conflict with Blazor's view of the DOM state.

So I came up with a hacky approach of generating a hidden button in my Razor view, e.g.:

```
<button id="arrow-left-button" @onclick="HandleArrowLeftPress"></button>
```

And then on the JavaScript side, I wired up a document event which finds that button by Id and calls .click() on it:

```
document.getElementById('arrow-left-button').click();
```

I know this seems truly awful, but it worked for what I was doing, which was using the arrow keys to move an absolutely positioned element on screen.

If anyone knows a cleaner way (like how to force an update of a Razor view by its name from the JavaScript side, in the handler callback), please let me know.

Comment: Hacky? Yep. Does it work? Yep!! :)

Answer (score 1):

To extend a bit on the answer by [Blightbuster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56452712/10650696)

For me at least the returned serialized event object would not cast to its .NET counterpart (`KeyboardEventArgs` in my case). I had to stringify it first

```js
var serializeEvent = function (e) {
    if (e) {
        var o = {
            //assign properties here
            //we can´t just stringify e since it has circular references
        };
        return JSON.stringify(o);
    }
};
```

And then deserialize in the .NET method called by the JSRuntime

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
T deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(
    s,
    new JsonSerializerOptions() {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    });
```

Also, if you are lazy like me and don´t want to look up the properties you need from the event, you can look up the property names in .NET before calling your js method

```cs
var propertyNames = typeof(T)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(x => x.CanWrite)
    .Select(x => $"{x.Name[..1].ToLower()}{x.Name[1..]}")
    .ToArray();
```

Then pass those to js and build your event object

```js
let o = {};
    propertyNames.forEach(propertyName => {
        o[propertyName] = e[propertyName];
    });
var serialized = JSON.stringify(o);
```

Finally I did not want to make a static method with the `[JSInvokable]` attribute, so I just made a little wrapper.

```cs
class JSInvokableWrapper<T>
{
    Func<T, Task> Func { get; }

    public JSInvokableWrapper(
        Func<T, Task> func)
    {
        Func = func;
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task Invoke(T argument)
    {
        await Func.Invoke(argument);
    }
}
```

Use that to wrap whatever func you want js to execute and turn the wrapper into a `DotNetObjectReference` (Maybe in some extension method for the `IJSRuntime`)

```cs
var dotNetObjectReference = DotNetObjectReference
     .Create(new JSInvokableWrapper<T>(func));
```

And call its Invoke method from js

```js
dotNetObjectReference.invokeMethodAsync('Invoke', param);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar situation and use the following approach as a workaround. You add event listener to a `div` tag, then set focus to that `div` such that your key presses can be captured.

```
<div tabindex="0" @ref="container" @onkeydown="onKeyDown" id="container">
//your snake game markup
</div>
@code {
    ElementReference container;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        await container.FocusAsync();
    }
    private void onKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs obj) { //your code here. }
}
```

You may need to remove the focus border of the `div` tag:

```
#container:focus-visible {
    outline: none;
}
#container:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can bind the event directly to a C# method, just using the event tag that you need (onkeyup/onmousemove ....) .

```
@page "/"

<div>
    <input type="text" onkeyup=@KeyUp />
</div>
@functions {
    void KeyUp(UIKeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Key);
    }

    protected override Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is an action binding on input tag, as I wrote in the question, this has a number of problems. I try to find a way to bind on document keyup event or any other way which will not have those restrictions

Comment: [Preview 9 changes UIKeyboardEventArgs to KeyboardEventArgs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/)