# C# Blazor: How to prevent specific key on input like in JS with e.preventDefault()?

Tags: c#, blazor

The problem seems very simple, but I didn't found any solutions yet.
I have a Blazor Input with an `onkeydown` event:

```
<input @onkeydown="@(e => KeyWasPressed(e))" 
@onkeydown:preventDefault="@PreventDefault" 
id="@GetId()" 
name="@GetId()" 
@bind-value="@InputValue" 
@bind-value:event="oninput" />
```

The User should write text, but with the arrow keys the user should navigate within a list (so I try to prevent the cursor to move to the top and the end of the text).

In JavaScript this could be something like this:

```
function KeyWasPressed(e)
{
    // key down
    if (e.keyCode == 40)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        // some work...
    }
    // key up
    else if (e.keyCode == 38)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        // some work...
    }
}
```

How to do this in Blazor? With `@onkeydown:preventDefault` you can prevent the **whole input**. If I set it to a variable (`@PreventDefault`), I can prevent only the **next** input (because the first input already happened). Just for understanding what I mean:

- PreventDefault FALSE > Input "H" > set PreventDefault to FALSE
- PreventDefault FALSE > Input "ArrowUp" > set PreventDefault to **TRUE**
- PreventDefault **TRUE** > Input "i" > set PreventDefault to FALSE

So Input will be (| = Cursor): H| > |H > |H

Which means the Cursor is wrong and the "i" was prevented.

Any ideas? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy solution for this at the moment. For that scenario you would still need to use a JS event handler and probably some interop if you want to call back into your .NET code.

You will find a very brief comment from Steve Sanderson about the reason (async handlers) here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14517#issuecomment-559184498

Another workaround is to bind your input to a variable and update the values manually. (also pointed out here [PreventDefault on Blazor input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328157/preventdefault-on-blazor-input) ) But this is probably a bumpy road.

Personally, I would love to see the preventDefault and stopPropagation as part of the EventArgs that are passed into the C# method handlers. I assume that this is technically challenging. However, it would simplify a lot of use cases. You might want to open a issue for this over at aspnetcore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seems Blazor needs a lot of more work until it becomes a real alternative to JS and JS Frameworks :(
The "PreventDefault on Blazor input" thing seems very limited, what about Copy/Paste or even TEXT with upperCase? This wouldn't work. I mean I had some similar idea: Prevent all and append all "allowed" keys to the input variable. But you have to read the shift key and wait for the next input to add something like "A" (uppercase), this is too bad.

Answer (score 6):

*(Years late but maybe this will help someone else.)*

*drocha87* pointed out that **this method only works with WebAssembly (wasm).**

The **onkeydown** even fires before the default so we can disable it immediately before using `@onkeydown:preventDefault=true.` The Idea for this came from [here](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-use-event-preventdefault-in-blazor.htm).

Note:

```
<input @onkeydown="KeyWasPressed"  @onkeydown:preventDefault="preventDefault" @bind-value="@InputValue" />

@code  {
  bool preventDefault = false;
  string InputValue = "";

  private void KeyWasPressed(KeyboardEventArgs e)
  {
      // key down
      if (e.Key == "ArrowDown")
      {
          preventDefault = true;
          // some work...
      }
      // key up
      else if (e.Key == "ArrowUp")
      {
          preventDefault = true;
          // some work...
      }
      else 
      {
          preventDefault = false;
      }
  }  
}
```

Comment: This is a very good idea, but seems to work only with wasm, I tried it with my server side blazor project, and despite that I can prevent the default to key up and down, it also prevents the next character I type once.

Comment: @drocha87 - Thanks for sharing that. I was using wasm so that aligns with what you said. I was actually running into something similar to you. I think I used onkeydown to set "preventDefault" then  onkeypress to record it - not sure if that helps but that was wasm.  Hopefully you find a server-side solution.

Comment: I ended up implementing the `preventDefault` with js interop. That was the only solution that worked fine in my case.  If you're interested I create a [repo](https://github.com/drocha87/blazorServerMentions) on github with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is following.

In JS create following method. It will catch the UP and DOWN keystrokes.

```
<script>
    function subscribeToChange(componentRef, inputRef) {
        console.log("subscribeToChange!");

        inputRef.onkeydown = function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == "38") {
                event.preventDefault();

                console.log("Up key pressed");
                componentRef.invokeMethodAsync('invokeFromJS');
            }
            else if (event.keyCode == "40") {
                event.preventDefault();

                console.log("Down key pressed");
                componentRef.invokeMethodAsync('invokeFromJS');
            }
        };

        inputRef.onkeyup = function (event) {
            componentRef.invokeMethodAsync('setValueFromJS', inputRef.value);
        };
    }
</script>
```

in razor:

```
<input @ref="Typing3" />
@HelloFromJSStr
```

in razor.cs:

```
    public ElementReference Typing3;
    public string HelloFromJSStr = "";

    [JSInvokable("invokeFromJS")]
    public async Task HelloFromJS()
    {
        //HelloFromJSStr += "A";
        //StateHasChanged();
        // do something here on UP or DOWN button presses..
    }

    [JSInvokable("setValueFromJS")]
    public async Task SetValueFromJS(string newValue)
    {
        HelloFromJSStr = newValue;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Here in my example you have 2 methods. One that is triggered `onkeyup` could be used to set **final** the value to the property (`HelloFromJSStr` ). If any other UI element needs a re-render then call `StateHasChanged()` method afterwards as in example. Rest is up to your imagination.

The remaining code part is initialization:

```
public partial class EventsAndRendering
{
    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType().Name}: OnAfterRenderAsync. firstRender: {firstRender}");

        if (firstRender)
        {
            var componentRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);

            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("subscribeToChange", new object[] { componentRef, Typing3 });
        }
    }

    // HelloFromJS()
    // SetValueFromJS(string newValue)
}
```

`DotNetObjectReference` is what allows us to invoke C# code from JS, without requiring to make the methods `static`s.

So the final flow is following:

1. after the page is rendered first time -> we create a reference to our main component as well as the reference to the inpout element.
2. we then use the above mentioned references to invoke the `subscribeToChange` JS method, which subscribes to events occurring on our input element.
3. Upon a keydown event we trigger method `HelloFromJS` in C#.
4. Upon a keyup event we trigger method `SetValueFromJS` in C#.

all above is just an example and must be adjusted per needs :)

inspiration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0#instance-method-call

**edit:** consider implementing `IDisposable` interface to dispose of .Net object:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    componentRef?.Dispose();
}
```